# Dapper: Help me run stored procedure with multiple user defined table types

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, dapper, user-defined-types

I have a stored procedure with 3 input paramaters.

```
... PROCEDURE [dbo].[gama_SearchLibraryDocuments]
@Keyword nvarchar(160), 
@CategoryIds [dbo].[IntList] READONLY, 
@MarketIds [dbo].[IntList] READONLY ...
```

Where IntList is user defined table type.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntList]
AS TABLE ([Item] int NULL);
```

My goal is to call this stored procedure with dapper.

I have found some examples regarding passing user defined type with dapper.
One of them is TableValuedParameter class implemented in Dapper.Microsoft.Sql nuget package.

```
var list = conn.Query<int>("someSP", new
{
Keyword = (string)null,
CategoryIds = new TableValuedParameter<int>("@CategoryIds", "IntList", new List<int> { }),
MarketIds = new TableValuedParameter<int>("@MarketIds", "IntList", new List<int> { 541 })
}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```

Written above code throws

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Dapper.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The member CategoryIds of type Dapper.Microsoft.Sql.TableValuedParameter`1[System.Int32] cannot be used as a parameter value
```

I have tested my stored procedure with one user defined table type and it worked fine.

```
conn.Query<int>("someSP", new TableValuedParameter<int>("@MarketIds", "IntList", new List<int> { 541 }), commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```

I need help with running original stored procedure.
Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Dapper has extension method to work with table valued parameters.

```
public static SqlMapper.ICustomQueryParameter AsTableValuedParameter(this DataTable table, string typeName = null)
```

You can use dapper in the following way:

```
var providersTable = new DataTable();
providersTable.Columns.Add("value", typeof(Int32));
foreach (var value in filterModel.Providers)
{
    providersTable.Rows.Add(value);
}
var providers = providersTable.AsTableValuedParameter("[dbo].[tblv_int_value]");

var filters =
    new
    {
        campaignId = filterModel.CampaignId,
        search = filterModel.Search,
        providers = providers,
        pageSize = requestContext.PageSize,
        skip = requestContext.Skip
    };

using (var query = currentConnection.QueryMultiple(StoredProcedureTest, filters, nhTransaction, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
{
    var countRows = query.Read<int>().FirstOrDefault();
    var temp = query.Read<CategoryModel>().ToList();
    return new Result<IEnumerable<CategoryModel>>(temp, countRows);
}
```

It will be translated into SQL:

```
declare @p3 dbo.tblv_int_value
insert into @p3 values(5)
insert into @p3 values(34)
insert into @p3 values(73)
insert into @p3 values(14)

exec [dbo].[StoredProcedureTest] @campaignId=123969,@search=NULL,@providers=@p3,@pageSize=20,@skip=0
```

Comment: I think a bit more explanation would be nice :)

Comment: Dapper has extension method to work with table valued parameters. public static SqlMapper.ICustomQueryParameter AsTableValuedParameter(this DataTable table, string typeName = null)

Comment: Just add the explanation to the answer :) Good answer by the way!Its just that pure-code answers mostly don't help in general, so as more explanation you give, the more useful it is for other users!

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar post at [Call stored procedure from dapper which accept list of user defined table type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269886/call-stored-procedure-from-dapper-which-accept-list-of-user-defined-table-type/41367519#41367519) with the following and I think this may help you as well!

I know this is a little old, but I thought I would post on this anyway since I sought out to make this a little easier.  I hope I have done so with a NuGet package I create that will allow for code like:

```
public class IntList
{
     public int Item { get; set; }
}

var list1 = new List<IntList>{new IntList{ Item= 1 }, new IntList{ Item= 2}};
var list2 = new List<IntList>{new IntList{ Item= 3 }, new IntList{ Item= 4}};

var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@Keyword", "stringValue");
parameters.AddTable("@CategoryIds", "IntList", list1);
parameters.AddTable("@MarketIds", "IntList", list2);

 var result = con.Query<int>("someSP", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.ParameterExtensions/0.2.0
*Still in its early stages so may not work with everything!*

Please read the README and feel free to contribute on GitHub: https://github.com/RasicN/Dapper-Parameters

Comment: I found this answer to be the most elegant solution to the problem of passing more than one Table Value Parameter to a Stored Procedure in Dapper.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a necro-post, but I believe there is a better way to do this. Specifically, a way that allows simple and complex types to be inserted and perform a single update, which may be important if you have a lot of indexes.

In this example I'm adding a Product that has a Name, ImageUrl and Year using a Stored Procedure called `ProductAdd` and a User-Defined Table Type called `ProductList`. You can simplify this to be a list of numbers or strings.

```
DataTable productList = new DataTable();
productList.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
productList.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ImageUrl", typeof(string)));
productList.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Year", typeof(Int32)));
foreach (var product in products)
{
    // The order of these must match the order of columns for the Type in SQL!
    productList.Rows.Add(product.Name, product.ImageUrl, product.Year);
}

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_appSettings.ConnectionString))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    var result = new List<Product>();
    try
    {
        result = await connection.QueryAsync<Product>("[dbo].[ProductAdd]",
            new { product = productList },
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
        );
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        // Permissions and other SQL issues are easy to miss, so this helps
        throw ex;
    }
}

return result;
```

The User-Defined Type is defined with this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ProductList] AS TABLE(
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ImageUrl] [nvarchar](125) NULL,
    [Year] [int] NOT NULL,
)
```

And the Stored Procedure uses the List passed in as a table. If you are using the same logic for a `GET`/`SELECT` and trying to use an `IN` you would use this same logic. A SQL `IN` is a `JOIN` under the covers, so we are just being more explicit about that by using a `JOIN` on a table in place of the `IN`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProductAdd
    @product ProductList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [Product] ([Name], [ImageUrl], [Year])          
    SELECT paramProduct.[Name]
        , paramProduct.[ImageUrl]
        , paramProduct.[Year]
    FROM @product AS paramProduct
        LEFT JOIN [Product] AS existingProduct
            ON existingProduct.[Name] = paramProduct.[Name] 
                AND existingProduct.[Year] = paramProduct.[Year]
    WHERE existingProduct.[Id] IS NULL
END
GO
```